# ¿Como recorrer un array dentro de otro array? PDFMake

Tags: javascript, array, pdf, map

Tengo un array que me devuelve n objetos, dentro de cada objeto de esos n objetos que devuelve hay un array con informacion. Necesito recorrer el primer arreglo y recorrer el segundo que esta dentro de el.

```
const body =  {
  "CONT": {
    "CON": [
      {
        "NI": ["33"],
        "NO": ["La Paz"],
        "NC": ["Bolivia"],
        "NE": ["10"],
        "DF": [
          {
            "CA": ["5 AVENIDA"],
            "NC": ["15-45"],
            "LT": [""],
            "AP": [""],
            "ZN": ["10"],
            "CL": ["Endocrinologo"],
            "CD": ["1"],
            "CM": ["1"]
          }
        ],
        "CAL": [""]
      },
      {
        "NI": ["9230"],
        "NO": ["Lons Trens"],
        "NC": ["Ciudad de Mexico"],
        "NE": ["28"],
        "DF": [
          {
            "CA": ["Locos ONG"],
            "NC": ["15-45"],
            "LT": [""],
            "AP": [""],
            "ZN": ["10"],
            "CL": [""],
            "CD": ["1"],
            "CM": ["1"]
          }
        ],
        "DPI": [""]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Necesito hacer una lista de los objetos en PDFMake

En PdfMake logro imprimir los datos del primer arreglo asi

```
  try {
    const dataPrincipal = () => {
      const newArray = [];
      body.CONT.CON.map((detalle) =>
        newArray.push([
          " ",
          "Numero de NI: " + detalle.NI,
          "Nombre : " + detalle.NO,
          "Comercial: " + detalle.NC,
          "NulE: " + detalle.NE,
          "DPI: " + detalle.DPI,
        ])
      );
      return newArray;
    };
    const list = dataPrincipal();

   

    const reportePdf = {
      document: {
        body: {
          footerImage: true,
          pagination: true,
          textFooter: {
            absolutePosition: {
              y: 50.87,
            },
            stack: [
              {
                text: [
                  {
                    text: " ",
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
            alignment: "center",
          },
          pageType: "Oficio",
          pageOrientation: "landscape",
          marginSymmetric: false,
          reportHeader: true,
          pageMargins: [85.04, 95.87, 85.04, 85.87],
          pageSize: {
            width: 612,
            height: 792,
          },
          content: [
            " ",
            {
              stack: [
                {
                  text: [
                    {
                      text: `Consulta la `,
                      lineHeight: 1,
                      bold: true,
                      style: {
                        alignment: "center",
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: "#0f3057",
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],

              margin: [0, 5, 0, 5],
            },
            " ",
            " ",
            "Detalles: ",
            " ",
            {
              style: "tableExample",
              table: {
                body: [
                  ["Detalles de la consulta"],
                  [
                    {
                      stack: [
                        {
                          type: "none",
                          ol: [list],
                        },
                        
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                ],
              },
            },
            " ",
            {
              stack: [
                {
                  text: [
                    {
                      text: " ",
                      lineHeight: 1,
                      bold: true,
                      style: { color: "#222e6c" },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
              margin: [0, 5, 0, 5],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
```

Ya logre recorrer y presentar solo la data del primer array, pero el segundo array que esta dentro de el primer array, aun no lo logro presentar he estado pensando si se puede hacer un map dentro de otro map. Pero dentro del cuerpo del pdfmake no se puede usar codigo js como for, funciones etc. Solo se pueden usar variables.

Comment: Todas las propiedades de los objetos del arreglo `CON` son arreglos. Cuál es el arreglo secundario que quieres leer?

Comment: El primer arreglo es **CON** el segundo es **DF** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const body =  {
  "CONT": {
    "CON": [
      {
        "NI": ["33"],
        "NO": ["La Paz"],
        "NC": ["Bolivia"],
        "NE": ["10"],
        "DF": [
          {
            "CA": ["5 AVENIDA"],
            "NC": ["15-45"],
            "LT": [""],
            "AP": [""],
            "ZN": ["10"],
            "CL": ["Endocrinologo"],
            "CD": ["1"],
            "CM": ["1"]
          }
        ],
        "CAL": [""]
      },
      {
        "NI": ["9230"],
        "NO": ["Lons Trens"],
        "NC": ["Ciudad de Mexico"],
        "NE": ["28"],
        "DF": [
          {
            "CA": ["Locos ONG"],
            "NC": ["15-45"],
            "LT": [""],
            "AP": [""],
            "ZN": ["10"],
            "CL": [""],
            "CD": ["1"],
            "CM": ["1"]
          }
        ],
        "DPI": [""]
      },
    ]
  }
}


// detalle principal
const newArray =  [];

body.CONT.CON.map((detalle) =>
        newArray.push([
          " ",
          "Numero de NI: " + detalle.NI,
          "Nombre : " + detalle.NO,
          "Comercial: " + detalle.NC,
          "NulE: " + detalle.NE,
          "DPI: " + detalle.DPI,
        ])
      );
      
//console.log(newArray);



// detalle secundario

const newArray2 =  [];

body.CONT.CON.map((detalle) =>

        detalle.DF.map(df => {
            newArray2.push([
              "CA: " + df.CA,
              "NC: " +  df.NC
          ])
        })
      );
      
console.log(newArray2);
```

Comment: No me funciono :(

Comment: Qué problema tienes? Actualicé la respuesta para agregar un ejemplo funcional.

Comment: Fijate que estoy trabajando con PDFMake, y necesito generar una lista de los n objetos (cada objeto sera una item de la lista), y al ya ejecutar tu ejemplo, todos los valores se imprimen en el PDF pero con valor "undefined"

Comment: Creo que es mejor que cambies la pregunta e incluyas lo que estás probando con PDFMake.

Comment: Ya la actualize, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Bien, solo agrega más detalles. Lo que has hecho con PDFMake. Cómo lo has hecho, cómo muestras el primer arreglo y como te gustaría que se mostrara el segundo, un ejemplo de como se deberían mostrar los datos. Entre más detalles hay  es más fácil encontrar la solución.

Comment: Listo, me gusta tu vibra, buena onda!!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113919/discussion-between-lobos-and-geracros).

Comment: Reestructure mi info y me funciono de la manera que me compartiste!